Python import from parent directory not working
I have the following code structure:
root_package/common.py - common package code imported from different submodules, tests etc.
root_package/core - core package functionality
root_package/test/test.py - tests for core

I have read the https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html. Not quite formal language, as usual, with lots of ambiguities, but whatever. What I got from it is that one can use dotted notation for intra-package references.
However, I could not not manage to import common.py from inside test.py, as neither of these worked:
from ..root_package import common.py
from ...root_package import common.py
or w/o "root_package"

It returned:

ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I have empty __init__.py files in root_package_dir and test subdir.
So do I have to resort to sys.path hack in my case?

For a module to be seen as a package, not only it must have __init__.py files in the proper places but it must have been loaded as a package. Said differently it must have been imported as its directory name, or directly executed with python - m package_name. If you directly execute of import a module that happens to be inside a package folder, none of the package goodies will be available - long story made short no relative imports.
